# How the sequence type is defined in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

```
type 'a node =
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * 'a t

and 'a t = unit -> 'a node

type 'a mappable = 'a t
```

What does `'a t = unit -> 'a node` mean in a type declaration? I thought that in a type declaration in ocaml we can only do an enumeration or call a constructor. 
thank you

Answer (score 2):

`unit -> 'a node` is the type of a function that takes no argument and returns a `'a node` (a node parameterized by `'a`). Example :

```
let f () = Nil;;
```

`type 'a t = unit -> 'a node` makes a synonym of the above type which is used in the first type defined in your code.

```
let l = Cons (4, fun () -> Cons (3, fun () -> Nil));;
let Cons(_,ll) = l;; (* ok , just for example, it returns a warning due to incomplete pattern matching *)
ll ();; (* - : int node = Cons (3, <fun>) *)
```

Comment: The example has a mix of OCaml syntax with Reason/Javascript/C++ comments

Comment: thank you for your answer but what is the purpose of declaring a function in these type?

Comment: the aim is not a declare a function like a type (... which are different objects...). Your code aims at mutually defining 2 types 'a node and 'a t. You could have written : type 'a node =
  | Nil
  | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a node);;  but then you will not be able to use 'a t later.  Also, have a look at http://typeocaml.com/2014/11/06/magic-of-thunk/.