# Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?) error

Tags: ocaml

function seq should return a sequence starting from init and at each time extends by step untill the condition is not verified:

```
let  rec seq init step cond () = 
let r = ref init in
if cond !r 
then  Cons(step !r, seq !r step cond)
else Nil
```

i tried these (to_list (seq 1  seq 1 (fun x -> x+1) (fun x -> x <10)) and i have 
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).

Comment: ````r```` is never updated

Comment: comment not related to your SO : why do you use () in  `let  rec seq init step cond ()`  ? why not simply `let  rec seq init step cond `?

Comment: if i use only like seq init step cond like you said it will return a 'a node not an 'a t

Comment: OK - I see, it is related to the other ticket you have posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49636168/how-the-sequence-type-is-defined-in-ocaml) in which you define those types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should avoid using reference without good reason. Then it is just a matter of storing the current value and not the next one:

```
let rec seq current step cond () =
if cond current then 
  Cons(current, seq (step current) step cond)
else
  Nil
```